# Codeigniter BUG?: Form validation class getting confused with arrays

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to create a form with the same group of fields (data is from database)

For example:

```
Group 1: Description field, Amount field, Others fields
Group 2: Description field, Amount field, Others fields
Group 3: Description field, Amount field, Others fields
```

So in my view I loop the database values:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($data_from_db as $data) {

  $description = array(
    'name'  => 'description[]',
    'id'    => 'description_field['.$i.']',
    'value' => set_value('description[]', $data->description)
  );

  echo form_label(lang('reward_description'), 'description_field['.$i.']');
  echo form_textarea($description);
  echo form_error('description[]');

  // more fields generated here in similar ways

  $i++
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description[]', 'lang:project_edit_description', 'required');

// more similar rules here
```

According to the [Codeigniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields) this is the correct way to do it, but its no working correctly.

Codeigniter is getting confused with the validation messages.

For example, if I leave **intentionally** one of the descriptions fields **empty** and submit the form, I get the validation error message in all the groups (I get "the Description field is required" also for group 1, 2 and 3)

Comment: You mean when one of the description fields from this line is empty `$reward->description` ?

Comment: no, the its a validation error after i submit, nothing to do with the line.

Comment: Well than you've completely contradicted yourself. You want the field to be required, but you are allowing description to contain null values??

Comment: I dont, thats why I want to get an validation message for the field but I am getting two validation messages instead of one. One for each field in the loop.

Comment: You should explain what you want to happen, and what is currently happening - including error messages.

Comment: I am telling you, THERE IS NO ERROR MESSAGES because there is NO ERROR at all. The PHP code is OK/VALID/GOOD/ERROR-FREE. The problem is with the CI validation class and the validation messages. Please read again  the question and comments...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885836/codeigniter-form-validation-when-creating-fields-using-a-loop

Comment: @Damien Pirsy: Maybe someone can answer one of those :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Rather than create a duplicate of your previous question, see the "[What if I don't get a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) section of the FAQ.

Comment: @jonathan How it was? Did you tried implement my answer? Indeed I had the same problem once and I think that this new solution is better. Please feedback... o/\o

Comment: @NomikOS: Thanks for your answer, I didn't have time to check your code, I will do it soon and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set rules for each indexed field. Following snippets show a working **example** (Improve it as you require):

---

Test controller:

```
function index()
{
    if ($_POST)
    {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($key == 'description' && is_array($value))
            {
                foreach ($value as $i => $vector)
                {
                    // set rule for each index
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description[' . $i . ']', 'description ' . ($i + 1), 'trim|required');
                }
            }
        }

        $this->form_validation->run();
    }

    $this->load->view('test');
}
```

---

Test view `views/test.php`:

```
<?php

echo form_open('');

$data_from_db = $_POST ? $_POST['description'] : array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
$i = 0;

foreach ($data_from_db as $data)
{
    $description = array(
        'name' => 'description[]',
        'value' => set_value('description[]', $data)
    );

    echo form_label('description ' . ($i + 1) . ':');
    echo form_textarea($description);
    echo '<br>';
    // set error for each index
    echo form_error('description[' . $i . ']');

    // more fields generated here in similar ways

    $i ++;
}

echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Try it');
echo form_close();
?>
```

This code will show `The description x field is required.` only in the empty fields.